# Log 500 Errors in WebApi 2

Tags: logging, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, interceptor

How can one log all Internal Server Error 500 errors returned by all actions in Web Api 2? How do you intercept the error to be able to log the Stack Trace ?

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to keep it simple and make sure I logged the exception.

Create an ExceptionFilter class like below

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        // actionExcutedContext.Exception is the exception log it however you wish
        Log.Exception(actionExecutedContext.Exception);

        actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new
                                                                                                                          {
                                                                                                                              actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message
                                                                                                                          });
    }
}
```

You also must configure WebAPI to call the filter.  This is done when you create your configuration.

```
config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
```

The `Log.Exception` line is just a helper class for me, you can log it however you choose.

Comment: To add to this, if you want this to catch all exceptions you can add it to the Global file on `ApplicationStart` with `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());`. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#registering-exception-filters) for more methods and info

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Elmah.MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) NuGet package.

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide
>   error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be
>   dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all
>   ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.
>
> Once ELMAH has been dropped into a running web application and
>   configured appropriately, you get the following facilities without
>   changing a single line of your code:
>
> Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions. A web page to remotely
>   view the entire log of recoded exceptions. A web page to remotely view
>   the full details of any one logged exception, including colored stack
>   traces. In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of
>   death that ASP.NET generated for a given exception, even with
>   customErrors mode turned off. An e-mail notification of each error at
>   the time it occurs. An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.

Once you register `Elmah` in your Web API project you can register custom filter in your web application which will log all unhanded exceptions out of the box.

```
public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //If you do not want to use Elmah, you can manually handle your ex here
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(context.Exception));
    }
}
```

You can register this custom filter in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

```
config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
```

Once configured you can check your error by browsing `/elmah` path from your root directory. (Your application is secured as this path will only be executed from hosted machine as per default configuration).

[image]